# Remove consecutive duplicate entries

Tags: r, duplicates, with-statement

How to remove consecutive duplicate entries in R? I think `with` may be used but can't think how to use it. Illustrating one example:

```
read.table(text = "
   a        t1
   b        t2
   b        t3
   b        t4
   c        t5
   c        t6
   b        t7
   d        t8")
```

Sample Data: D

```
    events    time
       a        t1
       b        t2
       b        t3
       b        t4
       c        t5
       c        t6
       b        t7
       d        t8
```

Required Outcome:

```
     events     time
       a        t1
       b        t4
       c        t6
       b        t7
       d        t8
```

`

Answer (score 12):

Yet an other one, assuming your `data.frmae` is named `d`:

```
d[cumsum(rle(as.numeric(d[,1]))$lengths),]
  V1 V2
1  a t1
4  b t4
6  c t6
7  b t7
8  d t8
```

Comment: +1 This was going to be my answer too. I read the OP question and when they said *remove consecutive duplicate entries* I thought to take the first of each using `cumsum( rle( df$Event )$lengths ) - rle( df$Event )$lengths + 1`

Comment: +1, definitely better then my somewhat challenging combination of `rle`, `mapply`, `split`, `tail`, `do.call`, ...

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Not exactly correct as it only shows one b row.
You can also use the duplicated() function

```
x <- read.table(text = "    events    time
   a        t1
   b        t2
   b        t3
   b        t4
   c        t5
   c        t6
   d        t7", header = TRUE)
#Making sure the data is correctly ordered!
x <- x[order(x[,1], x[,2]), ]      
x[!duplicated(x[,1], fromLast=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't quite give the OP's intended result. I never knew about `fromLast=TRUE` though - quite neat.

Comment: Oh darn! There were two b rows!

Answer (score 0):

A solution in base R using split-apply-combine works via the `tail` function which returns the last element and `rle` in combination with `mapply` to create a new vector of `events` that preserves the order in case of reappearing events:

```
x <- read.table(text = "    events    time
       a        t1
       b        t2
       b        t3
       b        t4
       c        t5
       c        t6
       b        t7
       d        t8", header = TRUE)


# create vector of new.events (i.e., preserve reappearing objects)
occurences <- rle(as.character(x$events))[["lengths"]]
new.events <- unlist(mapply(rep, x = letters[seq_along(occurences)], times = occurences))

# split into sublists per event
s1 <- split(x, list(new.events))

# get last element from list
s2 <- lapply(s1, tail, n = 1)

# combine again
do.call(rbind, s2)
```

This produces the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for the help but there is a slight change in the question. Also does the order remain same in using `tail`? I tried this and it is sorting events in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

And for good measure, using `head` and `tail`:

```
dat[with(dat,c(tail(events,-1) != head(events,-1),TRUE)),]

  events time
1      a   t1
4      b   t4
6      c   t6
7      b   t7
8      d   t8
```